# Django rest framework : different serializer following instance

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement a workflow process through the REST Api for an object to handle.

At the step 1, all fields could be written (except the status).

When calling a method (route on the viewset class), the status change (reflecting the change of the state of the object).

```
class ExaminationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Examination


    @detail_route(methods=['GET'])
    def invoice(self, request, pk=None):
        current_examination = self.get_object()
        current_examination.status = 1
        current_examination.save()
        return Response({'invoice':'waiting for paiment'})
```

Now it is not possible to edit some fields (but not all) on the object.

I thought that overriding get_serializer_class could be a solution, but the serializer class depends on the "state" of the instance. I'm not sure that it could be the way.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried implementing `get_serializer_class`? It should work to switch on the status flag there.